# Spatially Orienting 1,4 Dioxane Data From the EPA UCMR-3 Data Set

Tags: data-request, geospatial, data.gov, uses-of-open-data, metadata

I am attempting to draw conclusions about the source of 1,4 Dioxane, an emerging contaminant. In the last few years, the EPA released the UCMR-3 (Unregulated Contaminant Monitoring Rule) which had every large or medium sized public water supply test for the contaminant I'm interested in, 1,4 Dioxane. So I have a tremendous amount of data but there is no spatial references, no addresses to place it onto a map. I tried looking up each one individually through the EPA SDWIS or safe drinking water information system, [https://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/sdw_form_v3.create_page?state_abbr=NJ] and got some addresses but that would take forever since there 1400+ columns (representing samples) for New Jersey alone.

The question I am asking most simply is how can I get this EPA data with no addresses onto a map? I figure I have to find a list of addresses for public water supplies related to this UCMR data, if any exist? Need help.